# Is it shirk to think that thoughts affect reality?

Tags: shirk, kufr

Al Salam Alaykum. Before reverting to Islam, I looked into and tried to practice the law of attraction for a while. After I reverted I still hold the belief that if I think certain thoughts with the full belief that they are real, then they will happen in my life. Is this considered shirk?

Comment: When I was a child, I thought something similar about the weather, to make it rain or sunny. But this never worked. When I made duwa to Allah instead it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification if you think they are a means then it is minor shirk however if you think it can bring benefit or ward of harm then this is major shirk which takes you out of islam if you are not ignorant of the ruling

Answer (score -1):

This is kufr but you have not exited Islam because of you were ignorant